# Cloud Foundry Java Buildpack : how to change value in server.xml for Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I want to override the value **maxPostSize** property in the **Connector** element in the `server.xml` configuration file. (Set the maximum size to 1MB)

Is the only way to do this to fork the https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack and change the existing `server.xml` configuration file ?

Or is it also possible to add a `server.xml` somewhere in my WAR file, so that this one will be used instead of the one which is present in the buildpack.

Or can I also use JAVA_OPTS for that ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the only way to do this to fork the https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack and change the existing server.xml configuration file ?

With version 3.7+ of the Java build pack you can override the Tomcat configuration without forking the build pack.  The feature is called "External Tomcat Configuration".

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md#external-tomcat-configuration

Here's the gist of how it works.

- You make a TAR file of your `tomcat/conf` directory.  This can contain things like `server.xml`, `context.xml`, `web.xml` and anything that would normally go under Tomcat's `conf/` directory.
- You host an `index.yml` and that TAR file on an HTTP server some where.  If you don't have one, you can push it as an application to CF using the Static File build pack.
- You point the Java build pack to this configuration repo with the environment variable `JBP_CONFIG_TOMCAT`.  Here is an example: `"{ tomcat: { external_configuration_enabled: true }, external_configuration: { repository_root: \"url_to_repo\" } }"

More on the structure for the files on the HTTP server can be found [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/extending-repositories.md)

Comment: I found this option also on the help page, however this really sounds insecure and cumbersome to host this file somewhere. Maybe a better alternative is to use Spring-Boot with self-contained Tomcat where I can override some settings ?

Comment: Here is a good issue where in the comments the buildpack developers explain why they took this approach: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/316  Keep in mind you can host your configuration in a static application (using little memory) in the same space as your application.  Might help it feel a bit less heavy.

Comment: The HTTPS repository makes more sense if you think about it in terms of one configuration being used by multiple applications.  It is a little cumbersome if there's only one app that needs the special config.  Pushing your config as a small (ex: 32M) app on CF makes this a bit more palatable.  If you are adverse to going the HTTP server route, I suppose you could make a `.profile.d/` script which modifies the Tomcat config.  Script could be as simple as copying a config file you embed with the app or it could edit with `sed` or something like that.  It's a bit of a hack, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will document all of your official options:  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md#additional-resources

Neither of which are very simple/easy.

You could consider changing your application to a spring boot application.  I'm not a boot expert but I believe that the java buildpack can use a boot embedded tomcat even even if the packaging type is a .war.  In this type of configuration you might be able to use boot to customize how it starts the embedded tomcat to customize things like maxPostSize.